# Using postcss-conditionals with mixins

Tags: css, gulp, postcss, css-modules

I'm having an issue converting my postcss conditionals to css. I'm using gulp to process the files and output a css file. Everything seems to be working up until the point that I try to convert the conditionals (see below).

Here is my gulp file:

```
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('generate-css', function () {
  var plugins = [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-mixins'),
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    require('postcss-calc'),
    require('postcss-conditionals'),
    // require('cssnano'), -> commented out so that I can see what is being converted correctly
  ];
  return gulp
    .src('./src/pages/test/*.css')
    .pipe(postcss(plugins))
    .pipe(
      rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname = './src/pages/' + path.dirname;
        path.basename = 'testingStyles.module';
        path.extname = '.css';
      }),
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Here is a simplified version of my postcss file:

```
@import '../../theme/_mixins.css';
@import '../../theme/_variables.css';

.myClass {
  @mixin mixinOne;
  @mixin mixinTwo bottom, 10;

  &__icon {
    @mixin SVG logo_url, $my-color;
  }
}
```

The issue that (I think) that I am experiencing is that the mixins (which are imported) are not processed before `postcss-conditionals` tries to remove the `@if` statements.

This gives me this error:

```
postcss-conditionals: .../_mixins.css:4:3: Failed to parse expression
  3 | @define-mixin mixinOne $paramOne, $paramTwo {
> 4 |   @if $direction == all {
    |   ^
  5 |     margin: calc($spacer * $(factor));
  6 |   }
```

If I remove the `postcss-conditionals` plugin I get a css file with all of the previous plugins in the list succussfully applied (no nesting, vars correctly substituted, calcs transformed etc). There are no `@define-mixins` in the output css file if I remove the `postcss-conditionals` plugin.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to make sure that the `@define-mixins` are processed before it tries to remove the conditionals (the order of the plugins *seems* to be correct to me).

If anyone has some insight into what I'm doing wrong that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe there is some way to process the plugins in two passes? E.g. first `['postcss-import', 'postcss-mixins']`, then the rest? That would at least (dis)prove your theory

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the complete correct way to do it but I chained the plugins so that the conditionals plugin gets run on the output file of the previous plugins - and that seems to do the trick

Comment: @HaydnMorris can you share an example of how your chained the plugins (in your postcss.config.js)?